# How can I say "I have translation background" in Chinese?

Tags: translation

How can I say "x background" like "I have translation background" in Chinese?

Comment: You use x经历, as in experience of x.

Comment: Thank you so much. Can I use it like "我有翻译经历"?

Comment: Yes, that would be fine.

Comment: I've voted to close your question because it reads as a translation question for which no research effort has been shown. If this isn't the case, please indicate in the post what you have tried.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"背景" in Chinese can also be used to refer to people's background. Therefore it is okay to say "我有翻译背景". "经历" is also fine but it is "experience" in English. If you think your "background" means "experience" exactly, it is fine.

In universities we often say "你有计算机（专业）背景吗？" ("Do you have background in Computer Science?") If you have a degree in Computer Science then you definitely do. However, we probably don't think a degree in Computer Science counts as experience.